# Unchecking a Mac app's menu items before one is selected setState:NSOffState

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Mac app with a sub menu. Each item can be checkmarked to denote which one is active. I do this with code like this:

```
[sender setState:NSOnState];
```

However every time I click a new item the previous ones remain checked.

The [docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/MenuItemStates.html):

> In an action method that responds to all commands in the group use
>   setState: to uncheck the menu item that is currently marked:
>
> [currentItem setState:NSOffState];

I'm not really sure how this works. I'm quite new to Objective C and Cocoa. Does anyone have a tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have:

```
Item A
    Item 1
    Item 2
    Item 3
```

And you wanted it so that for items 1-3 only one can be checked at a time, what I would do is this: create IBOutlets for each menu item and group them into an array in awakeFromNib.  When you make your call(s) from each item, loop through that array, use `setState:NSOffState` to turn everything off, then use your `setState:NSOnState` call again to turn the freshly clicked item back on.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. However part of it shot right over my head. I don't think I've ever made an iboutlet (though I've used them) and this is the first time I've heard of awakeFromNib. Don't suppose you could give me a little more info to go on can you? (even just a link or search phrase that produces good results)

Comment: IBOutlets are just pointers.  http://tutorialsblogs.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-iboutlets/  awakeFromNib: http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/16

Comment: OK, thanks. With your help and also some help on IRC I've gotten it worked out. I created an outlet in my .h file: `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenu *menu;` then I ctrl+drag from my class in IB to the parent menu. Then in my code I was able to use this:    
    for (NSMenuItem *menuitem in _menu.itemArray) {
        [menuitem setState:NSOffState];
    }
Now it works!

Comment: Ah, yeah, the parent item was a nice shortcut.  Glad you got it working!